# javaScript doesn't run when loaded by ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javaScript function in `view/loadMoreDataWater.php`

```
<td ondblclick="updateCell()">
</td>
```

Now in `table.php` in `public_html` folder I have a table when onscroll is supposed to load more data:

```
qlimit =0;    
$("#waterDBTable tbody").scroll(function() {

    if ($("#waterDBTable").scrollTop() > $("#waterDBTable").height() - 300) {
         qlimit = qlimit + 5; 
         $("#loadingDiv").css('display','block');
         $.ajax({
            url: "controllers/loadMoreDataWater.php?qlimit=" + qlimit + "&table=water",
            success: function(result) {
               $("#waterDBTable").append(result);
               $("#loadingDiv").css('display','none');
            }
        });
    } 

});
```

Now when the content is loaded by ajax. ondblclick function is not working.
I found something about using

```
$(body).on('click', '#something', function() {
```

but I got confused and it didn't work for me, I didn't know in which file I must place such code.

Thank you

Comment: Loading the new content via an XHR request shouldn't have any effect on a call to the `updateCell()` function unless that function has been overwritten.

Comment: Do you see any error? If not, you should try putting `console.log()` inside the callback function to do some echo testing

Comment: @squint Oops. I tagged the wrong question. Withdrawing the flag/comment.

Comment: I wouldn't send XHR requests on an `onscroll` event without limiting the number of requests going out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were reading about [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

```
$('body').on('click', '#something', function() { 
  // do stuff
});
```

This code would add an event listener to the `body` element, listening for a `click` event and attaching a handler function to any `click` event which bubbled up from an element with an `id` of '`something`'.

The idea is *instead* of having an `ondblclick=` attribute, you attach one event listener like this:

```
$('body').on('dblclick', 'td', function() {
  // do whatever updateCell() does, using `$(this)` for the td that was clicked
});
```

So in effect you're *delegating* the event handler to one element. This is useful for several reasons, chief among them is that the body element doesn't go anywhere when you remove content and neither does the event handler need to be attached to new elements when being added to the DOM.

To understand how this works, reverse engineer it. Imagine what this is actually doing: all events bubble up from their source to the top level node. This means that every click event registers as a click on the event target (the element you're adding an event handler to) **and** on the body element, because you clicked the body too in clicking the element.

"So", one might wonder, "why add many event listeners to many individual elements when you can just add one giant event listener to the body and implement some switchboard logic in the event handler function?"

Without jQuery, you can do a basic event dispatcher like so:

```
document.body.addEventListener('dblclick', function(){
  var el = this;
  if ( el.classList.contains('dblclick-to-update') ){
    updateCell(el);
  }

  // other if statements could be below, handling other dblclick events, on elements other than td cells, if necessary
});
```

So, instead of saying:

- If this cell is clicked

  - Update it.

potentially dozens or even hundreds of times, we say:

- If there is a click anywhere in the page,

  - check what was clicked,

    - if it's something we want to update,

      - fire the updateCell function with the cell to update.

Ideally, each of your `td` elements would be given a CSS class like `class="dblclick-update"` or a data- attribute like `data-dblclickupdate="true"`, either of which you could then use as a selector for your delegated event handler. This would be instead of using '`td`' as a selector, which would screw up if you have other `td` elements which do not need to have the `updateCell()` behaviour attached to them.

So your code might look like this:

```
$('body').on('dblclick', '.dblclick-update', function(){
  updateCell($(this));
});
```

Using `updateCell($(this))` will give you the `td` which was clicked, but you'll need to change the `updateCell()` function to work with the element being passed in as a parameter. In your function definition, you'll need firstly to state that the function expects a parameter, so where you probably have this:

```
function updateCell() {
 // do stuff to 'this'
}
```

you need to define the function like this instead:

```
function updateCell(cell) {
  // do stuff to 'cell', which is passed in as a parameter now
}
```

Obviously, if you choose to use event delegation, you won't need those `ondblclick=` attributes anymore, so remove those and just have `<td class="dblclick-update"></td>` or something like that.

As for **why** the `ondblclick="updateCell()"` wasn't working for newly added `td` elements, my guess would be that you defined your `updateCell()` function **within** a `$(document).ready` block, which means that the function is not available to newly added elements because it's not in the global scope.

Try putting the function in the global scope instead, either by defining `updateCell()` outside of `$(document).ready` (and outside of any other functions for that matter) or by referencing it directly in the global `window` object like this:

```
window.updateCell = function(){ 
  // do stuff to cell
};
```

Or, if you use event delegation,

```
window.updateCell = function(cell){ 
  // do stuff to cell
};
```

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!! it seems to be working! but I still have a problem on how to pass the parameters from td !?

Comment: It's not working anymore! I receive this message in console Uncaught ReferenceError: body is not defined(…)

Comment: @user2305672 Sorry, I just fixed that in my answer: you need to use inverted commas around body. Like this: `$('body')` because it's a selector.

Comment: I tried 
$('body').on('dblclick','textarea',function (e) {
and everything works perfectly on the first page. but when ajax loads more content. this is not being applied to the new content. please help

Comment: Is there any way for me to see what you're working on?

Comment: sorry, I'm only working on localhost for now.
I'm trying to have a simple table like an excel sheet, you can double click on the cell to edit. on change the data will be saved into the database.
when you scroll the table it loads more rows by ajax call.
those new rows are not being edited on double click even while im using .on()

Comment: Ah fair enough. I understood what you said before, I'm just trying to imagine where the bug is most likely to be. Would you mind sharing the full event handler function you've written?

Comment: $('body').on('dblclick','textarea',function (e) {
     var cellID = e.target.id;
     document.getElementById(cellID).readOnly=false;   
    $("#"+cellID).css({'background-color':'#fff','color':'#c00'}); 
  });

Comment: Just to be absolutely sure, can I ask about these additional `textarea` elements you're appending -- do they get given an `id` when you append them?

Comment: yes sure, 
<textarea id='TS_Code-$x' readOnly='true' tscodex='$waterData[TS_Code]'>$waterData[TS_Code]</textarea>
they are given an id with increment variable $x

Comment: Yeah, I think the problem is that you can't put the dollar symbol in the `id` field because jQuery throws an exception. It's like a reserved symbol. Try it with another symbol, I think that will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your contributions.
The problem was in the id of the new embedded elements as it contained a variable and this variable caused duplication of the id.
it works fine now. thanks @amdouglas

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is this a competition entry? Just seems similar to something I helped somebody with by email recently.

Comment: lol, not at all. I am working on a project in my company. i am the only developer there

Comment: Ah, yeah I know that feeling. Why I went freelance in the end. Was already filling in for designer as well as developer at last permanent role I had, thought I might as well go indie and work flexible hours. lol